# Separating Audio and Video Steams

Tags: video, audio, theory

While I'm not sure whether Stack Overflow is the best place to ask this question, its the best I could come up with see how my google skills are failing me... Even though this question isn't specific to any language I think that people here should be able to help fill me in on the concepts and theory.

So, with that said...

I've seen quite a few services that rip the audio from say a youtube video. Seeing as I am curious to program with video and what not I thought achieving the same thing would be a rather beneficial and easy way to be introduced.

As for technical details on the subject I am lost. I don't have a good idea on the nitty gritty of how video play back works, and I am clueless to how one would separate those things through programming.

Thanks for the time and patience.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a broad question but I'll give it a try. There are basically two approaches:

1. Simulate playback, and capture the output audio somehow.
2. Download or eavesdrop to get the raw video stream from the server and save it to disk. Then, knowing the layout of the container format, extract the bitstream that encodes just the audio.

Option 1 can be implemented even if you can't reverse engineer the format, but I don't think it is a popular choice as it is slow, and requires encoding the audio once more, causing a possible drop in quality. So Option 2 is preferred.

I don't know the details about Adobe FLV streams (which is what YouTube uses), except that FLV is a container format that combines audio/video signals in a single stream. You will have to learn how to parse them (or find a library that will do it for you). You will also need to find the url for the flv stream you want to read. For testing, you can start with reading it from your temporary internet files after you played back the video.

Comment: I don't quite understand the concept. I'd think that if the sound is processed by the sound card it should somehow be accessible, which it is.... You think you could point me somewhere to read up on this? As of now I don't even know what I'd search for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the VLC application in the following way:

## just audio

vlc --daemon --ttl 7 --ipv4  "/home/user/song.mp3" :sout='#transcode{acodec=mp3,ab-128}:std{access=mmsh,mux=asfh,dst=:3333}' :no-sout-rtp-sap :no-sout-standard-sap :sout-keep

## just video

vlc --daemon --ttl 7 --ipv4  v4l2:///dev/video0  :v4l2-standard=0 :input-slave=alsa:// :sout='#transcode{vcodec=div3,vb=2000,scale=1,acodec=none}:std{access=mmsh,mux=asfh,dst=:3333}' :no-sout-rtp-sap :no-sout-standard-sap :sout-keep

Comment: If you do this you will convert the audio leading to worser quality.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at TAE, http://github.com/tuna74/TunaAudioExtracter . Please keep in mind that TAE only dumps the audio stream and only does transcoding if necessary.

Comment: Alright, thanks... But I was looking for more of the theory behind it. While I will definitely look at the source code for all of this, I'm guessing I won't be able to completely understand all that went into it. But once again thanks, this is definitely helpful.